# Decomposition of a time series into sinusoids

Tags: fourier-analysis, time-series, finance

I've noticed this interesting study on metatrader 4; see the picture below:

[image]

Where the financial timeseries is "decomposed" (deconvolved?) into a series of periodic sinusoidal functions. In the picture above the red line is the sum of three vectors (the two green and dark green/black) sinusoidal function.

I've looked into FourierDST and spectral analytical functions of Mathematica but wasn't able to approach this problem, could you please provide me me some pointers?

Comment: There are several ways to do this. If you have the data displayed, please share it. Otherwise, I will take some similar financial time series from [`FinancialData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html).

Comment: Might this be Empirical Mode Decomposition?  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28724/hilbert-huang-transform-package

Comment: @mikado I tried the Empirical Mode Decomposition (EMD), did not get good results -- see my answer. (I have to say I did not try that hard to get better results with EMD...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Applying Empirical Mode Decomposition

As suggested by @mikado in the comments:

> Might this be Empirical Mode Decomposition? See [mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28724/…](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28724/34008).

Does not work that well over the data obtained in the next section.
(A good suggestion nevertheless.)

[image]

## [Extracting Sin/Cos terms with Quantile Regression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191792/34008)

***Not a full answer, because I am not sure is this what OP wants. If it is then I will elaborate...***
First, I used data obtained with `FinancialData`:

```
ts2 = FinancialData["EUROX", {{2015, 7, 1}, {2017, 1, 1}, "Day"}];
DateListPlot[ts2, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Next, I followed the procedure described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191792/34008).

I derived/selected these curves:

[image]

Here are the corresponding terms:

[image]

### The code

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/\
MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]

ts2 = FinancialData["EUROX", {{2015, 7, 1}, {2017, 1, 1}, "Day"}];
DateListPlot[ts2, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", AspectRatio -> 1/4, 
 ImageSize -> 800]

ts2 = QRMonUnit[ts2]⟹QRMonTakeData;


bFuncs = Prepend[
   Flatten[Table[{Sin[b + h x], Cos[b + h x]}, {h, 1, 100, 1}, {b, 0, 1, 0.5}]], 1];
Length[bFuncs]

(* 601 *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 qrObj2 =
   QRMonUnit[ts2]⟹
    QRMonRescale⟹
    QRMonQuantileRegressionFit[bFuncs, 0.5]⟹
    QRMonSetRegressionFunctionsPlotOptions[PlotStyle -> Red]⟹
    QRMonPlot[PlotTheme -> "Detailed", AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> Large];
 ]

(* {24.2521, Null} *)


qFunc2 = (qrObj2⟹QRMonTakeRegressionFunctions)[0.5][t];

terms = Cases[qFunc2, (f_?NumberQ*c_) :> {f, c}];
TakeLargestBy[terms, Abs@*First, 6]
ListPlot[terms[[All, 1]], PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]

(* {{15.1087, Sin[0. + t]}, {6.00884, Cos[1. + 3 t]}, {1.95579,
   Sin[0. + 5 t]}, {0.875732, Cos[1. + 9 t]}, {0.549675, 
  Sin[0. + 11 t]}, {0.311493, Cos[1. + 21 t]}} *)
```

#### Re-do the fit with a more informed basis

```
largestTerms = TakeLargestBy[terms, First, 7]

(* {{15.1087, Sin[0. + t]}, {6.00884, Cos[1. + 3 t]}, {1.95579, 
  Sin[0. + 5 t]}, {0.875732, Cos[1. + 9 t]}, {0.549675, 
  Sin[0. + 11 t]}, {0.311493, Cos[1. + 21 t]}, {0.218136, Sin[0. + 18 t]}} *)

terms = SortBy[terms, -Abs[#[[1]]] &];

spans = {Span[1, 3], Span[4, 8], Span[9, 50]};
res =
  MapThread[
   Function[{terms, span},
    QRMonUnit[ts2]⟹
     QRMonRescale[Axes -> {True, False}]⟹
     QRMonQuantileRegressionFit[Prepend[terms[[All, 2]], 1], 0.5]⟹
     QRMonSetRegressionFunctionsPlotOptions[PlotStyle -> Red]⟹
     QRMonPlot[PlotTheme -> "Detailed", AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabel -> Row[{"span: ", span}]]⟹
     QRMonTakeRegressionFunctions
    ],
   {terms[[#]] & /@ spans, spans}
   ];

Block[{data = ts2, rData = qrObj2⟹QRMonTakeData, lines, rFunc},
 rFunc = Rescale[x, {0, 1}, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]];
 lines = Outer[{rFunc /. x -> #2, #1[#2]} &, res[[All, 1]], rData[[All, 1]]];
 Show[{
   DateListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3]}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed"],
   ListLinePlot[lines, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.004]}, 
    PlotLegends -> Map[Row[{"terms: ", #}] &, spans]]},
  ImageSize -> 800, AspectRatio -> 1/4
 ]]

GridTableForm[
 Map[{#, Simplify[
     terms[[#]][[All, 2]] /. 
      t -> Rescale[t, MinMax[ts2[[All, 1]]], {0, 1}]]} &, spans], 
 TableHeadings -> {"span", "terms"}]
```

Comment: Spot on, please share the code.

Comment: @JeromeIbanes Just posted the code -- tell me if you have any problems running it or you need more explanations.

Comment: I seem to be getting quite different results, please review below:

[https://www.eskimo.com/~jibanes/tmp/aa.pdf].

Comment: @JeromeIbanes The data is not ingested properly. Try to replace `ts2` with a simple array with two numerical columns. Which Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: Thank you Anton!