# Why Fourier doesn't show me the peaks?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm trying to identify the frequencies in my time history samples, and I can see a frequency in the time history, but can't see it in its Fourier transform.
Here it is :

the sample data:

```
dt = 0.01;(*0.01 second per sample*)
ls={7.18384,9.08503,7.13301,9.03243,7.23692,8.82911,7.48153,8.50053,7.8291,8.09453,8.22514,7.67123,8.60473,7.29656,8.90489,7.02926,9.07228,6.91356,9.07469,6.96968,8.90404,7.19156,8.58122,7.54573,8.15062,7.97689,7.67665,8.41549,7.23096,8.78898,6.88426,9.03305,6.69172,9.10231,6.68698,8.97821,6.87272,8.6724,7.22283,8.22643,7.68225,7.70488,8.17857,7.18711,8.62957,6.75303,8.9597,6.47266,9.10889,6.39174,9.04594,6.52704,8.77139,6.85901,8.32088,7.33824,7.7584,7.88776,7.16829,8.41967,6.64141,8.84366,6.2609,9.0868,6.08919,9.10045,6.15615,8.87392,6.45525,8.43236,6.94108,7.83828,7.53853,7.17843,8.15053,6.55427,8.67686,6.06288,9.02603,5.78403,9.13458,5.76455,8.97352,6.01177,8.55858,6.48966,7.94428,7.12458,7.22101,7.8152,6.49678,8.4485,5.88528,8.91739,5.48272,9.13786,5.35709,9.06375,5.53107,8.69409,5.98259,8.07629,6.64157,7.29757,7.40537,6.47512,8.14882,5.73434,8.74894,5.19349,9.09985,4.93916,9.13459,5.01757,8.83338,5.41929,8.23096,6.08644,7.41062,6.91285,6.49317,7.76769,5.61863,8.50777,4.92325,9.00806,4.51966,9.1747,4.47503,8.96814,4.80297,8.40434,5.455,7.55984,6.33198,6.55581,7.29271,5.54458,8.18165,4.6821,8.847,4.10633,9.17184,3.91187,9.08704,4.13559,8.59066,4.74753,7.74309,5.65489,6.66645,6.71462,5.51928,7.75486,4.47976,8.6024,3.70977,9.10911,3.33653,9.17844,3.42289,8.77952,3.96388,7.95795,4.87716,6.82561,6.02223,5.55073,7.21349,4.32513,8.25592,3.34263,8.96977,2.75835,9.22521,2.67336,8.96055,3.10556,8.19668,3.99626,7.03496,5.20525,5.6427,6.54315,4.23034,7.78851,3.01522,8.73391,2.19205,9.20894,1.89461,9.11841,2.17992,8.45091,3.00859,7.29079,4.25733,5.80068,5.727,4.20335,7.18224,2.74288,8.37806,1.64996,9.10926,1.10137,9.23383,1.19232,8.70843,1.91736,7.5871,3.1692,6.02681,4.75307,4.25335,6.41448,2.53923,7.8804,1.14864,8.89922,0.307694,9.28655,0.154088,8.95041,0.725381,7.91675,1.93765,6.31868,3.60713,4.38985,5.46625,2.41628,7.21338,0.707136,8.55287,-0.470752,9.2482,-0.919297,9.15831,-0.561298,8.26386,0.562301,6.67532,2.27715,4.61492,4.31759,2.39053,6.34975,0.340327,8.03907,-1.21045,9.08947,-2.01384,9.30485,-1.9283,8.61208,-0.958302,7.08603,0.756819,4.93354,2.94639,2.47094,5.26353,0.0706556,7.32281,-1.89254,8.77714,-3.10504,9.358,-3.36416,8.93794,-2.61487,7.53742,-0.963082,5.34406,1.33854,2.66827,3.9233,-0.0836731,6.37173,-2.49189,8.2693,-4.17005,9.28401,-4.84777,9.20861,-4.3986,8.01348,-2.88195,5.83756,-0.523299,2.99222,2.304,-0.10749,5.14496,-2.98081,7.52648,-5.18357,9.04878,-6.32959,9.4304,-6.18952,8.56459,-4.73628,6.56344,-2.13332,3.70414,1.31944,0.401559,5.19872,-2.85418,9.0291,-5.5357,12.3241,-7.17454,14.6869,-7.4465,15.8834,-6.29832,15.9227,-3.97558,15.044,-0.986409,13.6463,2.07958,12.1451,4.72194,10.8576,6.6742,9.93404,7.90659,9.37837,8.56294,9.10124,8.84598,8.99267,8.93815,8.96116,8.95636,8.95544,8.95677,8.95391,8.95455,8.95365,8.95341,8.95371,8.95173,8.95356,8.95088,8.95381,8.9499,8.95321,8.94933,8.95282,8.94887,8.9513,8.94838,8.95018,8.94857,8.94853};
```

Fourier transform function:

```
DFT[A_, ht_] := RotateRight[ht/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]*Fourier[RotateLeft[A, Length[A]/2 - 1], 
              FourierParameters -> {1, 1}], Length[A]/2 - 1];
(*shift the zero frequency to the center*)
```

plot the time history:

```
ListPlot[ls, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, dt*Length[ls]}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

We can see there are a fast frequency with period about 0.02s and a slow frequency with period about 1.5s, but in the Fourier transform we only see the fast frequency(except the zero frequency)

```
ListPlot[Abs[DFT[ls, dt]]^2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {- 1/dt/2, 1/dt/2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

So where is the low frequency?

---

**Update**

As Simon and bill suggest, the slow oscillation is the beating of two close high frequencies. 
Since the Fourier transform resolution is 2Pi/(N*dt), where N is the number of sample points, so if I increase the resolution by increasing the number of sample points I should see two separated peaks.
So I tried to increase the number of sample points, but I can only see one peak all the time.
Here is how I did it:

```
w = 5.0; dt = 0.66125;
f[x_] := Sin[w x]

ls = Table[f[x], {x, dt, 200 dt, dt}];
```

we see beating in the plot

```
ListPlot[ls, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {dt, 200 dt}]
```

[image]

but one on peak in the Fourier transform:

```
ListPlot[Abs[DFT[ls, dt]]^2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {-1/dt/2, 1/dt/2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If we increase the number of sample points, we still only see one peak:

```
ls2 = Table[f[x], {x, dt, 800 dt, dt}];

ListPlot[Abs[DFT[ls2, dt]]^2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {-1/dt/2, 1/dt/2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

So where is the problem?

Comment: If you have v9, try `Periodogram[ls, SampleRate -> 100]`. The 0 Hz spike has distinct shoulders, but the 0.66 Hz signal cannot be disambiguated. This suggests some windowing is needed, but playing with it, I can't seem to pull it out, either.

Comment: I think this is more of a signal processing question than a *Mathematica* one. What you see in your data is beating between two high frequencies. You can completely zero the low frequencies and you'll still see it, e.g. `ft = Fourier[ls]; ft[[;; 150]] *= 0; 
ft[[-150 ;;]] *= 0; ListLinePlot[Re[InverseFourier[ft]]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods if it is because of beating, I would expect to see two separated peaks if I increase the Fourier transform resolution, but I did't see it. See my updates.

Comment: Sorry, I was oversimplifying. The "other" frequency peak is an alias reflected on the other side of the Nyquist frequency 1/(2dt). The beat frequency is twice the difference between your signal frequency and Nyquist `fbeat = 2(w/(2Pi)-1/(2dt)) = 0.079`

Comment: @SimonWoods does the "other" frequency really exist in the (improperly sampled) signal or not? Which is correct to say, (1) even we can see a beating in the time history, the "other" frequency may not really exist in the signal, or (2) there are two frequencies exists in the signal and we can see their beating, but we can see only one of them. And could you point me to some references of the Nyquist frequency, especially where you get "an alias reflected on the other side of the Nyquist frequency"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is only a single frequency in the underlying signal of course, but attempting to reconstruct that signal from a set of samples gives the low frequency modulation you see in your plots. The point is that you shouldn't expect to see that low frequency in the DFT. I can't give you any specific references, the Wikipedia article on aliasing is probably a good place to start.

Comment: If you want to dig deeper, the book 'Digital Filters' by Hamming, published by Dover is a great resource on the topics of sampling, aliasing and DFT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening in your second example (with the single sine wave giving the "beating") is that you have exceeded the [Nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency): what you are seeing is called [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). Here's a simple way to explore this (using your DFT function):

```
dt = 0.66125; 
f[w_, x_] := Sin[w x];
Manipulate[ls = Table[f[w, x], {x, dt, 200 dt, dt}];
   Column[{ListPlot[ls, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {dt, 200 dt}], 
           ListPlot[Abs[DFT[ls, dt]]^2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
           DataRange -> {-1/dt/2, 1/dt/2}, Axes -> False,  Frame -> True]}], {w, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

If you play with the slider, you'll see a single sine wave up to the Nyquist frequency (in both the time and frequency plots). When you get higher than the Nyquist frequency, the signal can do many things, among them show the beating that you noticed. Observe that the frequency line begins to descend as the frequency increases (just after you pass Nyquist). When this has certain relationships to the frequency of the sine wave, you get the beating effect.

So -- in your first question, where we could not see the source of the data (you just gave us a list of values) we had assumed you sampled correctly (i.e., below Nyquist). Simon's guess about beating was a good one. In the second question, you have created a sine wave and are sampling it improperly... there are many things that can go wrong once you do this.

Comment: hi; I think there is a typo: `below the Nyquist rate` should be `above the Nyquist rate`

Comment: @Nasser -- I think I corrected it... I was improperly using "rate" and "frequency" as synonyms.

Comment: @bills I've read the reference you linked, but I'm still not quiet understand. Isn't that the Fourier transform should contains all the frequency information in the signal? How is that mathematically possible to have a beat but only one frequency? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: What you are thinking of is the (continuous-time) Fourier transform, which indeed would have only one frequency. Mathematica's `Fourier` command is the DFT (discrete Foureir transform), and if you break the Nyquist frequency, all sorts of things can happen (as you can see above). Below the Nyquist frequency, the analogy between the (continuous-time) Fourier transform and the DFT is close. Said another way, if you were sampling fast enough, this would not happen.

Answer (score 6):

Simon has hit the problem on the head (those are not real frequency components you see). But there is a way to discover what these frequencies are, by taking the envelope of the signal and transforming (DFTing) the envelope.

```
data = ls - MeanFilter[ls, 5];
decay = 0.06; rise = 0.2;
filt[z_, u_] := Max[decay z + (1 - decay) u, rise z + (1 - rise) u];
env = Drop[FoldList[filt, 0, Abs[data]], 1];
```

The first line removes the "DC" components from the data and the following lines are a method of extracting the envelope, taken from my answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27748/elegant-way-of-obtaining-the-envelope-of-oscillating-function). (Detail: the `Drop` is needed because your DFT function doesn't work for odd-length sequences).

[image]

Taking the DFT (using your function) of this signal `env`, and plotting

```
ListPlot[Abs[DFT[env, dt]]^2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
      DataRange -> {-1/dt/2, 1/dt/2}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

shows the low frequency part of the signal that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. But as you showed the beating frequency is about 6Hz, that means the two frequency should separated apart about 12Hz, but why it is not shown in the Fourier transform? Could you have a look at my updates?