# plotting a trig functions along with its envelope

Tags: plotting, envelope

**Note**: This questions is quite different from the ones referred to in the comments. Those deal with numerical questions, while this one is algebraic.

I have plots of the following type:

```
Plot[Cos[50 t] + Cos[51 t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

I would like to plot a envelope over this plot, i.e. another plot that joins all of maxima and minima of this plot respectively. Here is my attempt, but it's not exactly what I'd like:

```
Plot[{Cos[50 t] + Cos[51 t], Cos[t] + 1.5, -Cos[t] - 1.5}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

How can I generate the actual envelope?

Comment: I'm guessing that's something like `Cos[42x]+Cos[43x]`?

Comment: this is completely true but this is for the Fig.1, I want to access to sheath while I do not access to any formula for that.

Comment: Well, you've got to give us some kind of input to start with.

Comment: I plotted these ones with: Plot[{Cos[50 t] + Cos[51 t], Cos[t] + 1.5, -Cos[t] - 1.5}, {t, 0, 10}], I used of simulated functions 'Cos[t] + 1.5' and '-Cos[t] - 1.5' for the sheath.

Comment: In that case, your sheath is given pretty much perfectly by $\pm 2\cos(t/2)$, but maybe that's not what you want?

Comment: Yes, it was exactly I want. thank you so much. Now, I must think why for every frequency, we can use of the +-2Cos[t/2].

Comment: Ok. I can understand why for every frequency which are different with the one the frequency of the sheath will be 1/2 and for different equal to 2, sheath frequency will be 1 and so on.

Comment: I edited your question.  You should make sure that I preserved your intended meaning.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of [Elegant way of obtaining the envelope of oscillating function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27748), which is a duplicate of [Mathematica envelope for the bottom of a plot, a generic function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2350).  But this one just straight trigonometry.

Comment: Also see: [(4667323)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4667323)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Playing with the manipulate below might help. It's based on the the [acoustics of beats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28acoustics%29).

```
Manipulate[Plot[
  {Cos[a*t] + Cos[b*t], 2*Cos[(b - a) t/2], -2*Cos[(b - a) t/2]}, {t, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Opacity[0.7]], 
   Directive[Black, Thick], 
   Directive[Black, Thick]}],
 {{a, 20}, 1, 50}, {{b, 21}, 1, 50}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. this is correct

Answer (score 19):

Don't mind me, I'm just having fun.

Grab the definition of `HilbertTransform` from [this previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/350/484), and then:

```
f[t_] := Cos[50 t] + Cos[51 t] + Sin[53 t] (* more sinusoids = more fun *)
g[t_] := Evaluate@HilbertTransform[f[τ], τ, t]
h[t_] := Abs[f[t] + I g[t]]
Plot[{f[t], h[t], -h[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 100,
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Black, Black}]
```

[image]

You can see that the envelope has a nice analytical form:

```
ComplexExpand[h[t]] // FullSimplify
```

> $\sqrt{3 + 2\cos t + 2\sin 2t + 2\sin 3t}$

Further reading: [analytic representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal).

Comment: This way though doesn't seem to catch when the envelope should go to zero. Shouldn't it e.g. vanish near 2?

Comment: Should it? It still looks like a sinusoid with small but nonzero amplitude there. (The envelope correctly goes to zero for the original function in the question, if that's what you're concerned about.)

Comment: Ah, OK then, you're right.

Comment: @Rahul: wow! that's really cool! Would this also work on a set of discrete data? Something like ListLinePlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]]] ... If not, how could one modify it so that it does? I have a bunch of data that makes a seemingly random curve like that and I'd like be able to integrate over some area under the curve like the one that you generated.

(Hmmm, i just copy pasted your code, but didn't get the black curve :( what could have gone wrong?)

Comment: @Solarmew: You first need to copy the definition of the Hilbert transform from the post I linked to. It also gives a discrete version of the transform, which you could use in much the same way on discrete data.