# Envelope for harmonic oscillator

Tags: differential-equations, envelope

I am able to take the expression $\cos 11t-\cos 12t$ and use the sum to product identity to write it in the form
$$\left(2\sin\frac t2\right)\sin\frac{23}{2}t.$$
I can then plot the function and use the slower oscillating part as an "envelope" for the function.

```
Plot[{2 Sin[t/2] Sin[23 t/2], 2 Sin[t/2], -2 Sin[t/2]}, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image]

Does someone have a way of changing the expression
$$12\sin11t-11\sin 12t$$
into a similar form so that I can again use part of the new form for the envelope of this function?

Comment: possible duplicate: [plotting a trig functions along with its envelope](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49043/125)

Answer (score 11):

You can use HilbertTransform for these things. M does not have HilbertTransform, but easy to make it. Using the Hilbert transform definition from this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/341/implementing-discrete-and-continuous-hilbert-transforms) and using the definition of the envelope being the absolute part of $f(t)+I h(t)$ where $h(t)$ is the Hilbert transform gives

```
hilbertTransform[f_,u_,t_] := 1/Pi FullSimplify[Convolve[f, 1/u, u, t,PrincipalValue -> True]];
```

and now

```
f[t_] := 12 Sin[11 t] - 11 Sin[12 t];
h = hilbertTransform[f[t], t, u];
Plot[{f[t], Abs[f[t] + I (h /. u -> t)]}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get both sides, just change the sign

```
z = Abs[f[t] + I (h /. u -> t)];
Plot[{f[t], z, -z}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: There's something I don't understand.  The `hilbertTransform` gives a different answer than the OP's and my approaches.  It seems that one of them must be incorrect. (That is, each may be a correct answer to different questions.)  Can you clarify?  There must be different definitions of envelope, perhaps.  See for example [Envelope_(waves)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)#Example:_Beating_waves) (wikipedia).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am using the envelope as defined in DSP terminology. Please see the second method here (the Hilbert transform method) [envelope-detection-1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/envelope-detection-1.html) and this is how how I do it in Matlab. (in Matlab, the discrete version of Hilbert transform is used, via fft/ifft method as the implementation). Here is full example of envelope detection using Hilbert [envelope-extraction-using-the-analytic-signal](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/envelope-extraction-using-the-analytic-signal.html)

Comment: Thanks. What little I know about signal processing I learned in an electronics laboratory course in 1983, but I probably learned about beats in physics in H.S.

Comment: @MichaelE2 beating waves is not really envelope detection. It does look like it, sure, but I assumed the question is about envelope detection for signals. I remembered doing this for a HW sometime ago, that is all, but had to look up the details now again.

Comment: The OP's example makes it seem to be about beats to me.  I think it's a question of definitions - and there's yet another [math. def. of envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)). :)  In any case I learned something new - thanks, again!

Comment: @Michael E2: I wish you would put your answer back on this page. It was extremely helpful, precisely what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way via solving for the parameters in the trigonometric identity:

```
expr = 12 Sin[u t] - 11 Sin[v t];
form = a Sin[(v - u) t/2 - b] Sin[(v + u) t/2 - c];
sol = First@Solve[
     Most@DeleteCases[Flatten@CoefficientList[
          expr - form // TrigReduce // Simplify // TrigExpand,
          {Sin[t u], Cos[t u], Sin[t v], Cos[t v]}
          ], 0] == 0] /. C[_] -> 0;
form /. sol /. {u -> 11, v -> 12}
(*
  -22 Cos[(23 t)/2] Sin[t/2]
*)
```

(There are four nonzero coefficients and only three unknowns, hence `Most`.)

```
Plot[{-22 Cos[(23 t)/2] Sin[t/2], 22 Sin[t/2], -22 Sin[t/2] }, {t, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Mike, fascinating, wonderful answer, but this looks like a wrong answer. Try -22 Cos[(23 t)/2] Sin[t/2] == 12 Sin[11 t] - 11 Cos[12 t] /. {t -> 0}. You can also Plot[-22 Cos[(23 t)/2] Sin[t/2], {t, 0, 4 Pi}], then Plot[12 Sin[11 t] - 11 Cos[12 t], {t, 0, 4 Pi}] and you will see different graphs.

Comment: Ooops. My mistake! Sorry. I have a Cos where I should have a Sin.

Comment: @David No, I think you're right...Hmm. I'll investigate.

Comment: @David I think it's wrong and I haven't figured out how to coax the right answer out of *Mathematica*.  I'll undelete it, but please double check that it is correct.  Thanks.

Comment: It is so close to being correct, but yes, it is not the same as 12sin11t−11sin12t. Evidence is [here](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/spring2015/MathematicaProblems/MichaelE2.nb). However, I still hope you work at this, because I find it very interesting and it helps me learn more about the possibilities using Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Not to compete the excellent answer of Nasser, but to look at the problem differently I propose the following. Let

```
f[t_] := 12*Sin[11 t] - 11*Sin[12 t];
```

Then one can look for the extremum points of this function:

```
 eq1 = D[f[t], t] == 0

(*  132 Cos[11 t] - 132 Cos[12 t] == 0  *)

sl = Solve[eq1, t];
```

There is a lot of solutions here. Let us make a list of those only belonging to the first period:

```
    lst1 = Table[Drop[sl[[i, 1, 2, 1]] // N, -1], {i, 2, Length[sl]}]

(*  {-3.005, 3.005, -2.73182, 2.73182, -2.45864, 2.45864, -2.18546, 
2.18546, -1.91227, 1.91227, -1.63909, 1.63909, -1.36591, 1.36591, 
-1.09273, 1.09273, -0.819546, 0.819546, -0.546364, 0.546364,
-0.273182, 0.273182}  *)
```

They all yield the abscissas of the extremum points. 
Let us now form the list of both the abscissas and ordinates:

```
    lst2 = Map[{#, f[#]} &, lst1];
ListPlot[lst2]
```

and visualize them:

[image]

That's it already, but it can be plotted better than that:

```
       lst3 = Sort[
   Select[lst2, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] >= 0 || #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] < 
        0 &]];
lst4 = Sort[
   Select[lst2, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] < 0 || #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 
        0 &]];

Show[{ListLinePlot[{lst3, lst4}, InterpolationOrder -> 2],
  ListPlot[{lst3, lst4}]
  }]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

Have fun!