# Is it possible to ask Mathematica to obtain the function describing the upper and lower boundaries of a combinations of functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions, maximum

Assume that I have three one-variable non-periodic functions $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ for $x>0$. The question is: is it possible to ask Mathematica to obtain the function describing the upper and lower boundaries of these three functions (I am not sure if it is called enveloping function)? Something like the red curves in the second picture attached (I plot it manually); I am looking for an analytic expression for the function describing these red curves.

```
f[x_] = 2 x Sin[x];
g[x_] = x Cos[x];
h[x_] = x + Sin[3 x];

Plot[{ f[x], g[x], h[x]}, {x, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

P.S. This is just a simple example, my real functions are much more complicated than the given ones; I just wanted to know if there is any hope to do that.

[image]

Comment: This might be a start https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49043/8822 . BTW, if you look for *envelope* on this site you will find many more similar Q&A.

Comment: @mattiav27 Thanks; but my question is if it is possible to obtain the analytic expression for the envelope function; is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
f[x_] = 2 x Sin[x];
g[x_] = x Cos[x];
h[x_] = x + Sin[3 x];
min[x_] = Min[f[x], g[x], h[x]];
max[x_] = Max[f[x], g[x], h[x]];
Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x], min[x], max[x]}, {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Brown, Orange, Green, Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yep... straightforward.  ($+1$)

Comment: Thank you very much. My question was if t is possible to obtain the analytic expression for the function describing your green curves; is it possible?

Comment: @math2021:  In general these functions will be discontinuous and hence best expressed using the min or max functions.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork But each function (upper and lower) is continuous; so, do you mean that it is not possible to determine the functions describing them?

Comment: I should have said "discontinuous derivative."  What kind of answer could you even imagine for the "simple" case of $f_1(x) = x, f_2(x) = x^2 - 1$?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.